# Stored Procedure SQL statement ignored

Tags: stored-procedures, peoplesoft, peoplesoft-app-engine

I am compiling this stored procedure and getting few errors:  Trying to compile this in oracle SQL developer.

> SQL statement ignored
>   Invalid character

Code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CGF_GEN_WIP( NUM IN VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
       SEQ_NBR 
    FROM 
       PS_CGF_SEQ_TBL 
    WHERE 
       SEQ_NAME = 'CGF_WIP_ID'; 

    UPDATE PS_CGF_SEQ_TBL 
    SET DTTM_STAMP_SEC = %CURRENTDATETIMEIN, SEQ_NBR = SEQ_NBR + NUM
    WHERE SEQ_NAME = 'CGF_WIP_ID';
END;
```

Kindly advise me on this, I am starting new. Thank you!

Comment: Remove the ; at the end of the lines

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: `"CGF_WIP_ID"` is a column name not a string literal in SQL

Comment: @Serpiton: The `;` is used to terminate individual statements in SQL (the "query language"). The code looks very much like Oracle's PL/SQL and you most definitely need the semicolons there and in essentially every other procedural language. SQL Server doesn't require them, but you should use them nevertheless: https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons

Answer (score 1):

The %CURRENTDATETIMEIN Meta-SQL is only available inside peoplecodes and PeopleSoft SQLs. You cannot  use that on a stored-procedure.
I recommend you to write an App Engine to do your code, that's the usual way to develop process in peoplesoft.
But if you have to stay with the SP, just change this for SYSDATE.

Answer (score 0):

In PeopleSoft the Meta SQL %CURRENTDATETIMEIN is translated to "CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP)" if the underlying database is ORACLE.   You can know this typing your PeopleSoft SQL in a new SQL object in then PeopleSoft Application Designer tool.  Once you finish typing the SQL right click and select "Resolve Meta SQL" from the pop up menu.  You will see the Oracle SQL translation in the Meta SQL tab on the output window.  Search the index for "meta-SQL, resolving" in Oracle's [PeopleTools 8.52 PeopleCode Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41509_01/pt852pbh2/eng/psbooks/tpcd/book.htm).

To fix your stored procedure make the following change:
Change "UPDATE PS_CGF_SEQ_TBL SET DTTM_STAMP_SEC = %CURRENTDATETIMEIN, SEQ_NBR = SEQ_NBR + NUM WHERE SEQ_NAME = 'CGF_WIP_ID';"

To "UPDATE PS_CGF_SEQ_TBL SET DTTM_STAMP_SEC = CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP), SEQ_NBR = SEQ_NBR + NUM WHERE SEQ_NAME = 'CGF_WIP_ID';"